# Writing Haxe code _inside_ php? for laravel

Tags: haxe

I want to use the laravel framework from within haxe.

Is there any option to write haxe code into php files directly, with access to the php surrounding objects of that file, and have it compile to php?

it would be interesting for me because I miss some things in php.

for example like so:

```
<php

use somecool\Lib\CoolClass;

//myhaxecode

  var playerA = { name: "Simon", move: Paper }
  var x = //somehow access CoolClass

//myhaxecode end

 var_dump($playerA);
?>
```

doesnt need to be haxe, but I dont seem to be able to find anything else

is this possible?

Comment: Does it have to be inlined into the PHP code? I don't think there's any existing tool for that, though you could probably build something yourself with a bit of effort. AFAIK the preferred way would be to expose your PHP code using `extern` definitions and write the Haxe code completely separately

Answer (score 2):

[PHP magic](http://old.haxe.org/doc/advanced/magic#php-magic), such as `untyped __php__("php code")` can be utilized for direct interfacing.

Injecting auto-generated code into handwritten code doesn't sound like such a good idea, but you could add a post-build step for that (directly or via [Context.onAfterGenerate](https://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/Context.html#onAfterGenerate)).

Comment: In Haxe 4, "php magic' is old syntax. You better use `php.Syntax.code("php code")` instead. See more https://haxe.org/manual/target-syntax.html